# Filtering table rows with higher date than provided

Tags: zend-framework, filter, rows, zend-date

I'm currently trying to do it that way:

```
// Creating date object  
$date = new Zend_Date(); 

// Adding to it 4 weeks
$date->add('4', Zend_Date::WEEK); // it's expire day                

// Getting date in integer(i guess it's unix timestamp yes?)
$date->get();

// Saving it to Mysql in field 'expire' with type Varchar
```

Then, when needed to get rows, that have date bigger(that haven't yet expired), than current I just add to SQL a simple statement WHERE expire >= $current_date.

Or there is better way to do it? Or how it happens usually?

Comment: Why don't just use a DATE type ? btw, '// Getting date in integer' should be stored with INT, not VARCHAR.

Comment: Does my answer not answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the native MySQL DATETIME column in your table.  This is how you'd retrieve the date for MySQL:

```
$date->get('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```